# TinyMCE 5 color_map setting not showing custom colors

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I need to customize the colors inside TinyMCE 5 color pickers. In the documentation I have found:

[color_map](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#color_map)

but I cannot make it work:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: '#textarea_id',
            height: 500,
            menubar: true,
            relative_urls : false,
            remove_script_host : false,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor colorpicker',
                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | strikethrough forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link paste',
            style_formats: [

                { title: 'Badge', inline: 'span', styles: { display: 'inline-block', border: '1px solid #2276d2', 'border-radius': '5px', padding: '2px 5px', margin: '0 2px', color: '#2276d2' } }

              ],
            color_map: [
                "000000", "Black",
                "993300", "Burnt orange",
                "333300", "Dark olive"

              ],
            paste_as_text: true,
            content_css: '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'

        });
```

My expectation is to see a color picker composed of only 3 colors for foreground text color and background text color but instead I see the standard color picker. Why ?

Comment: Using your color_map settings I created a TinyMCE Fiddle and it appears to do exactly what you want: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/RHgaab.